# Java synchronisation poll

Tags: java, synchronization

Here's some code I saw once. Can you see what's wrong with it?

[updated]

```
public class ResourceManager1
{
    private final String mutex = "";
    Object resource = null;

    public Object getResource()
    {
        synchronized (mutex)
        {
            if (resource == null)
            {
                resource = new Object();
            }
        }

        return resource;
    }
}

public class ResourceManager2
{
    private final String mutex = "";
    Object resource = null;

    public Object getResource()
    {
        synchronized (mutex)
        {
            if (resource == null)
            {
                resource = new Object();
            }
        }

        return resource;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh goody, more downmarking without commenting. Was it that I used Java rather than C#?

Comment: Probably that it's not really a question for discussion or help.. it's basically a trivia quiz. Some people probably don't go for that in a question...

Comment: Just for the record (just noticed this) it's probably a little weird to use the British/Australian '-isation' in the title -- even though I prefer it, the java keyword is -ize so that might make it more searchable. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Never synchronize on strings, particularly string literals which are interned. You've basically just got a single lock.

In general, never synchronize on any reference that might be visible outside your class (including "this") *unless* the purpose of the external visibility is precisely for locking purposes. I usually use a `private final` variable created solely for the purpose of locking.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same String as a mutex for both classes and hence only one of the synchronized blocks can be used at a time, which does not seem to be the intention of the code.

Comment: It's not the immutability of Strings which is the problem here - it's interning of string literals. Java *could* have kept immutable strings but not done interning, in which case this code would have worked.

Comment: Ah, true...I knew what I meant but said it badly. Which we all know is not a good thing for a programmer to do, thanks for the correction. :)

Comment: yep, could have used mutex = new String("");

:)

Answer (score 0):

mutex is not final and resource is not private.

Besides, you need a getResource method that returns resource, but I suppose this is just a typo.